# IIS NTLM problems

Tags: iis, ntlm

I have set up a website in IIS to use Windows Authentication, went to providers and i have NTLM under Enabled providers...  i followed this post to set up security policys.   http://developers.de/blogs/damir_dobric/archive/2009/08/16/enabling-of-ntlm-on-windows-7-and-windows-server-2008-r2.aspx

I am getting he error:

NTLM server blocked audit: Audit Incoming NTLM Traffic that would be blocked

Audit NTLM authentication requests to this server that would be blocked if the security policy Network Security: Restrict NTLM: Incoming NTLM Traffic is set to Deny all accounts or Deny all domain accounts.

If you want this server to allow NTLM authentication, set the security policy Network Security: Restrict NTLM: Incoming NTLM Traffic to Allow all.

Am i missing something?  I have set the security policy Network Security: Restrict NTLM: Incoming NTLM Traffic to Allow all.